# Only get the size from "du" command, not the folder names

Tags: macos, unix, applescript, du

I am doing an applescript that is supposed to set the size of an folder to an varible. This is the code so far:

```
set sizeVar to do shell script "du -skh -m /Users/JS_Admin/Desktop"
```

Output:

```
"4242   /Users/JS_Admin/Desktop"
```

The thing is that I only want the size in numbers, no space or directory location.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Specifying both `-k` and `-m` does not make sense: either you want 1-Mbyte or 1-Kbyte blocks. Also `-h` does not make sense in combination with `-k` and `-m`. Only the last one `-m` will be considered

You can use `cut` to remove anything after the space:

```
du -sm /Users/JS_Admin/Desktop | cut -f1
```

With `-f` you specify which field you need (in this case the first one).

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `awk`.

```
du -s /path/to/folder | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

`$1` refers to the first column. And regarding `du -s`:

```
-s, --summarize
     display only a total for each argument
```